# Use json_decode on a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

im trying to decode a 2-dimensional array in php with json_decode.

I create my array like this:

```
    $query3 = 'SELECT * FROM `files` WHERE `company`="'.$_POST['company'].'"';
    $result3 = mysql_query($query3);
    $return_type = "files";
    $data_files;
    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_object($result3))
    {
        $data_files[] .= json_encode(array("cat" => $row3->cat, "name" => $row3->name)); 
    }
```

at the bottom of my code i use this:

```
$return = json_encode($data_files);
```

my result looks like this:

```
["{\"cat\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Flyer Vorwerk C-40 11\\\/2013\"}","{\"cat\":\"4\",\"name\":\"Katalog Sommer 2013\"}","{\"cat\":\"5\",\"name\":\"Beutel wechseln\"}","{\"cat\":\"5\",\"name\":\"Teppich sauber kriegen\"}","{\"cat\":\"3\",\"name\":\"Flyer Vorwerk C-70 11\\\/2013\"}"]
```

sadly there are too many qutoes, but when i remove the first `json_encode();` in the mysql section the result looks like this

```
["Array","Array","Array","Array","Array"]
```

i could remove the qutoes with preg_replace(), but i want to know if there is a better solution.

i would really appreciate your help.

btw, sry for my crappy english!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$data_files = array();
while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_object($result3)) {
    $data_files[] = array("cat" => $row3->cat, "name" => $row3->name);
}
return json_encode($data_files);
```

Don't double encode your values!

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I already tried it, my result will look like ["Array","Array","Array","Array","Array"]

Comment: That's not possible with the code shown. What exactly are you doing with the data to get that result?

Comment: I use print to show it, nothing more. I just need to see the result in JSON-format.

Comment: If you `print` the result of my above code, you get perfectly fine JSON with the right number of quotes. If you loop through a PHP *array* and `print` it, it'll print `'Array'`, because that's how `print` outputs arrays. Use `var_dump()` instead.

Comment: It doesnt work either, but i manually created a two-dimensional array and it worked. So there must be something wrong in the "creation" of my array i guess.

Comment: Show more code, anything relevant from the creation of the array over JSON-encoding it to the point where you're outputting it. Again, using the code you show there's *no way* you get `Array` as output anywhere.

Comment: Ahhhh im so stupid :D there was a point! `$data_files[] .=` Thank you for your help =)